# Need to update Percentage bar with thread in adapter class on Click

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am working on a voting app in which SomeOne Upload two or more images and another user vote on any particular image.

Now Everything is working fine but i have to add a functionality in which when Someone clicks on the image the circular progress bar should show progress one by one.

Currently what is happening is if someone clicks on the image I calculate the current voting percentage add new percentage and call notifyitemchange(Position)

What I want is if a score is 30% then the progress bar should show it from 0 to 30 %

[image: This is image]

```
         else if (PO.getFeed_type().equalsIgnoreCase("vertical")){
                view.card_parent.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                view.card_parentS.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                view.card_parentV3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                view.card_parentV4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                view.card_parenttext.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                view.card_parentpost.setVisibility(View.GONE);


                //  System.out.println("jdixkdicxk+++3"+PO.getTitle());

                view.titleH.setText(PO.getTitle());
                view.usernameH.setText(PO.getUsername());
                view.vote_countH.setText(String.valueOf(PO.getAnswered_poll()) + "");
                view.created_timeH.setText(PO.getCreated_time());
                view.comment_countH.setText(PO.getComments_count());


                Picasso.with(getActivity())
                        .load(Constant.imagepath + PO.getChoice1())
                        .error(R.drawable.no_image)
                        .into(view.choice1H);

                Picasso.with(getActivity())
                        .load(Constant.imagepath + PO.getChoice2())
                        .error(R.drawable.no_image)
                        .into(view.choice2H);


                if (PO.getProfile_pic().length() > 0)
                    Picasso.with(getActivity())
                            .load(Constant.user_imagepath + PO.getProfile_pic())
                            .error(R.drawable.dummy_user)
                            .into(view.profile_picH);
                else {
                    Picasso.with(getActivity())
                            .load(R.drawable.dummy_user)
                            .error(R.drawable.dummy_user)
                            .into(view.profile_picH);
                }


                if (PO.getSelected_choice() == 1) {
//                holder.choice1_selected.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//                holder.choice2_selected.setVisibility(View.GONE);
//
//                holder.choice1_percentage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//                holder.choice2_percentage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    int percentage1 = PO.getChoice1_percentage();
                    int percentage2 = PO.getChoice2_percentage();

                    view.donut_progress1H.setProgress(percentage1);
                    view.donut_progress2H.setProgress(percentage2);

                    view.donut_progress1H.setText(String.valueOf(percentage1) + "%");
                    view.donut_progress2H.setText(String.valueOf(percentage2) + "%");

                    view.white_layer1H.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    view.white_layer2H.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);



                    view.myvote1H.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    view.myvote2H.setVisibility(View.GONE);


                    //view.choicebar1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    //view.choicebar2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                } else if (PO.getSelected_choice() == 2) {
//                view.choice1_selected.setVisibility(View.GONE);
//                view.choice2_selected.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//
                    view.white_layer1H.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    view.white_layer2H.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    int percentage1 = PO.getChoice1_percentage();
                    int percentage2 = PO.getChoice2_percentage();

                    view.donut_progress1H.setProgress(percentage1);
                    view.donut_progress2H.setProgress(percentage2);

                    view.donut_progress1H.setText(String.valueOf(percentage1) + "%");
                    view.donut_progress2H.setText(String.valueOf(percentage2) + "%");

//                
view.choice1_percentage.setText(String.valueOf(percentage1));
//                
view.choice2_percentage.setText(String.valueOf(percentage2));



                    view.myvote1H.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    view.myvote2H.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                } else {

                    view.choicebar1H.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    view.choicebar2H.setVisibility(View.GONE);


                    view.white_layer1H.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    view.white_layer2H.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                }



                if 
(myuserobj.getUser_pk().equalsIgnoreCase(PO.getUser_fk()))
                    view.follow_btnH.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                else
                    view.follow_btnH.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                view.choice1H.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        if (PO.getSelected_choice() == 0) {


                            PO.setSelected_choice(1);
                            PO.setChoice1_count(PO.getChoice1_count() + 1);

                            PO.setAnswered_poll(PO.getAnswered_poll() + 1);

                            float choice1_percentage = ((float) 
PO.getChoice1_count() / (float) PO.getAnswered_poll()) * 100;
                            float choice2_percentage = ((float) 
PO.getChoice2_count() / (float) PO.getAnswered_poll()) * 100;

                            PO.setChoice1_percentage((int) 
choice1_percentage);
                            PO.setChoice2_percentage((int) 
choice2_percentage);



//                                getAllPollsFollowing();

//                        feedlistview.smoothScrollToPosition(position+1);

                            PO.setSelected_choice(1);
                            notifyItemChanged(position,PO);
                            vote_poll(myuserobj.getUser_pk(), 
String.valueOf(items.get(position).getPoll_pk()), "1");

                        } else {

                            Intent in = new Intent(getActivity(), 
PollDetailActivity.class);
                            in.putExtra("poll_pk", 
String.valueOf(PO.getPoll_pk()));
                            startActivity(in);
                        }
//                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Already voted", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                    }
                });

                view.choice2H.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {


                        if (PO.getSelected_choice() == 0) {


                            PO.setSelected_choice(2);
                            PO.setChoice2_count(PO.getChoice2_count() + 1);
                            PO.setAnswered_poll(PO.getAnswered_poll() + 1);


                            float choice1_percentage = ((float) PO.getChoice1_count() / (float) PO.getAnswered_poll()) * 100;
                            float choice2_percentage = ((float) PO.getChoice2_count() / (float) PO.getAnswered_poll()) * 100;

                            PO.setChoice1_percentage((int) choice1_percentage);
                            PO.setChoice2_percentage((int) choice2_percentage);



                            items.get(position).setSelected_choice(2);
                            notifyItemChanged(position,PO);


                            vote_poll(myuserobj.getUser_pk(), String.valueOf(items.get(position).getPoll_pk()), "2");


                        } else {

                            Intent in = new Intent(getActivity(), PollDetailActivity.class);
                            in.putExtra("poll_pk", String.valueOf(PO.getPoll_pk()));
                            startActivity(in);
                        }


                    }
                });
```